# While loop causing Unity to freeze

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, while-loop, freeze

So I'm trying to use a while loop to have my program find a path through an 8x8 array. However, on launch Unity stops responding and has to be closed. Can someone help explain why my code doesn't work as I don't see anything wrong with it as the condition for the loop to end is changed. Here is the source code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LevelGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

public int counter = 0;
int LevelX = 0;
int LevelY = 0;

int[,] LevelData = new int[8,8]{
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
};

void Start () {
    Generate();
}

void RandomPath(){
    int NewDirection = Random.Range(0,3);
    if(NewDirection==0){
        if(LevelX!=0){
            if(LevelData[LevelX-1,LevelY]==0){
                counter++;
                LevelData[LevelX-1,LevelY]=counter;
                LevelX=LevelX-1;
            }
        }
    }else if(NewDirection==1){
        if(LevelX!=7){
            if(LevelData[LevelX+1,LevelY]==0){
                counter++;
                LevelData[LevelX+1,LevelY]=counter;
                LevelX=LevelX+1;
            }
        }
    }
    else if(NewDirection==2){
        if(LevelY!=7){
            if(LevelY!=0){
                if(LevelData[LevelX,LevelY-1]==0){
                    counter++;
                    LevelData[LevelX,LevelY+1]=counter;
                    LevelY=LevelY+1;
                }
            }else{
                counter++;
                LevelData[LevelX,LevelY+1]=counter;
                LevelY=LevelY+1;
            }
        }
    }
}

void Generate(){
    //picks a random location for the level to start and the second room, then generates a random path to the bottom of the level
    int LevelStartX = Random.Range(0,8);
    int LevelStartY = Random.Range(0,5);
    counter++;
    LevelData[LevelStartX,LevelStartY] = counter;
    Debug.Log(LevelStartX);
    Debug.Log(LevelStartY);
    int Direction = Random.Range(0,3);
    if(Direction==0){
        if(LevelStartX==0){
            counter++;
            LevelData[LevelStartX+1,LevelStartY]=counter;
            LevelX = LevelStartX+1;
            LevelY = LevelStartY;
        }else{
            counter++;
            LevelData[LevelStartX-1,LevelStartY]=counter;
            LevelX = LevelStartX-1;
            LevelY = LevelStartY;
        }
    }else if(Direction==1){
        if(LevelStartX==7){
            counter++;
            LevelData[LevelStartX-1,LevelStartY]=counter;
            LevelX = LevelStartX-1;
            LevelY = LevelStartY;
        }else{
            counter++;
            LevelData[LevelStartX+1,LevelStartY]=counter;
            LevelX = LevelStartX+1;
            LevelY = LevelStartY;
        }
    }else{
        counter++;
        LevelData[LevelStartX,LevelStartY+1]=counter;
        LevelX = LevelStartX;
        LevelY = LevelStartY+1;
    }
    while(LevelY!=7 || counter!=32){
        RandomPath();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It is happening because `LevelY` is **never** equals to `7` and `counter` is **never** equals to `32` so you get infinite loop.

Comment: But counter is incremented most iterations of the loop and LevelY is increased when NewDirection equals 2 and the space above the current one has a zero in it.

Comment: @DoYouEvenFish Testing is easy. Put a break point after your while loop and run your code

Comment: There are many `if` conditions that are required to be met before `counter` or `LevelY` are incremented or modified. What if these conditions are not met?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @DoYouEvenFish, in your code, `Generate` function may increment `counter` several times, that's why it may be jumping over `32`. Instead of using `!=` use `<=`. E.g. `counter <= 32`

Comment: Thank you @L.B for saying that I should put break points in, I've managed to get it working now because of that. Also, thank you EZI for the article you linked to as that was also quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and found out that counter never reaches 32 (or at least usually). It is probably because you are using random numbers, it stops at a different number everytime you run it, so there is a small chance it will actually work